# SQLite: Using update to Copy a value-specific row from one table to another

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to insert all rows that are male from one table into another table. However, I have got this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

I have done some research and have found out that you can't have a where statement in an insert statement. The answers from the answers have told me to use UPDATE.

However I don't know how can I use UPDATE to carry out the following command.

```
selectMaleRow = cur.execute("INSERT INTO " + nameGroup + " SELECT * FROM " + sessionName + " ORDER BY random() WHERE Gender='M' Limit 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query has the `ORDER BY` clause before the `WHERE` clause. It needs to come after.

Comment: Thanks. But I have got this error `sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: formI.ID` even though I don't have any contents in the formI table. However there should have been row copied to the formI table.

Comment: That is a different question. The syntax error in `SELECT` that you reported is now fixed. What you now have is a runtime error caused by the failure of the `INSERT`. We can't possibly tell why that is failing without knowing the structure of the table `formI` and whatever table is named in `nameGroup`.